# newusers causes segfault

Tags: users, segmentation-fault

I am trying to bulk-add 433 users via `newusers`.

The `newuserlist.txt` file I have contains users with up to 16 chars usernames with questionable patterns (numbers at the beginning and capital letters).

However, trying to do:

```
# newusers newuserlist.txt
```

just quits with

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and doesn't add any user. Is newuserlist.txt too large?

Comment: Congratulations!!!!!! you've found an ugly bug, please notify the manteiner of the package/s so that the bug is fixed and we all can benefit from it. In Debian systems you can use `reportbug` to inform the mantainers.

Comment: In order to help with your question the information contained in newuserlist.txt would help. I guess you set it up according to paswd's field format, since that is the format the manual says it should have with the execptions pointed out in the manual `man newusers`.

Comment: I did. Here the newuserlist file: [link](http://pastebin.com/9juZK2YE)

Comment: Have you identified the line that spawns the segfault? On a quick scan the lines appear to be OK (The number of fields is correct, even though I don't know if the password field can be blank)

Comment: The password can be blank. And the second one.

Comment: The page's been removed, so I don't know what the second one had. Any way, since `newusers` is giving you the segfault, why don't you give `useradd` a try? It may be not be as straight as the other one, but with a simple script with 4 lines or so you can do the same job.

Comment: OK, thank you. It is safe to close this question now.